# Clinical prediction rules (calibration, discrimination and validation) in R

Tags: r

This is my glm model which I was able to create but I now want to do the Hosmer Lemeshow GOF test but get this error which I don't understand-

```
Call:
glm(formula = BC.result ~ Diabetic + Low.diastolic + Pulse, family = 
"binomial", data = Data2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0805  -0.4559  -0.3144  -0.2437   2.8259  

 Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.86311    0.98715  -5.939 2.86e-09 ***
Diabetic       1.21963    0.37395   3.262 0.001108 ** 
Low.diastolic  1.27095    0.35074   3.624 0.000291 ***
Pulse          0.02361    0.00780   3.027 0.002470 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 276.40  on 485  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 249.71  on 482  degrees of freedom
(14 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 257.71
> hl<- hoslem.test(model3$BC.result, fitted(model3, g=10))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(y0 = 1 - y, y1 = y) ~ cutyhat) 
: 
variable lengths differ (found for 'cutyhat')
```

Can anyone explain this error with the Hosmer Lemeshow goodness of fit test?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, a package will be so much easier with 1 line of code given you are not familiar with programming. Try the `boot` library. Otherwise it would be useful to learn basics of R.

Comment: Your question seems to be [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please try to reduce the scope, and write a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the R language.

Comment: We'd like to help, but asking people to write your code for you is not the way SO works; can you show what you've tried to do so far?  Have you googled "hosmer lemeshow R" yet?  or "c-index R"?  These both bring up useful results for me ...

Comment: Yes I've tried all that. Will edit the question with all the error messages I got. Thanks

Comment: You have missing values in your data, so `fitted(.)` is 14 observations shorter than your data frame.  Try `na.omit()` ... ? Once again, a [mcve] will be helpful ...